# BMS battery build DIY help

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, diy

I am making a battery charger for a speaker using 4 18650 3.7V batteries.

Now I know that I would need to get a 4S Lipo or Li-ion PCB, the only thing I don't understand is the current rating that I should get.

Like, for example, would getting a 30A 14.8V PCB board cause an issue somewhere?

Also since the voltage of the battery board is 14.8V, would I have to go a little beyond for the DC charging port and its charger?

Comment: Many things can cause issues and you question is light on detail so this cannot be answered.

Comment: Ah I apologise, but the design will be similar to something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK15V.jpg 
https://gyazo.com/8f8f1009b7dbd68d6bd0bcb07302437a
https://gyazo.com/d9a6a47ba4df2881c697fd2297cd803c
Ignore the numbering on the power adapter since I got this from someone else,  but it is similar to this concept. The voltage rating on the Bluetooth amp that this will be connected to is 12V, the only thing I don't understand is whether 30A is too much to be connected to a circuit like this, also would this mean I would have to get a 14.8V to connect to the dc port to charge?

Comment: I work with data sheets, specifications and proper schematics so I can't help this time.

Comment: Ok no problem but thank you for the advice

Comment: What do you mean by "30A 14.8V PCB"? Are you talking about the BMS for the 4 individual batteries?

Comment: I mentioned the PCB just from what I knew, but yeah I mean that

Comment: Well on that case, you shouldn't have to worry about the voltage. My assumption is that they're marketing the product for 14.8V since that's the nominal voltage of 4 cells in series. The 30A max current eating shouldn't be an issue either since I don't believe you'll be charging your batteries at 30A. But with that in mind, I'd question if you'd want to use this BMS with the high current safety limit.